# SwiftUI - Passing post.id to a ViewModel

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swiftui

I am trying to add a comments feature, where obviously each post will have its own set of comments. To do this, I am trying to pass post.id (from PostRow.swift) to a function in my CommentsViewModel. However, since nothing is *directly* calling on the function, I am unsure how to do this. For example, in some of my other functions, all I had to do was add (id: post.id) to the parameter: `postData.checkForLikes(id: post.id)`. Then, in the actual function, all I had to do was `func checkForLikes(id: String)`.

Like I said, nothing is directly calling on this function getComments. Here is the code for this:

*PostRow.swift - button to show comments*

```
                    showingComments = true
                    //unsure if an action to update postID should be here?
                }){
                    Text("Comments")
                }
                .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingComments)
                {
                    CommentsView(post: post)
                }
```

*CommentsView.swift - view*

```
@StateObject var commentsData = CommentsViewModel()
```

```
ScrollView{
                    VStack(spacing: 15){
                        
                        ForEach(commentsData.comments){comment in
                            
                            CommentsRow(post: post, comment: comment, commentData: commentsData)
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .padding(.bottom,55)
                }
            }
```

*CommentsRow.swift - actual format for each comment, only including for knowledge of CommentsRow references*

```
struct CommentsRow: View {
    
    var post : PostModel
    var comment : CommentsModel
    @ObservedObject var commentData : CommentsViewModel
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    
    var body: some View {
}
```

*CommentsViewModel.swift*

```
class CommentsViewModel : ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var comments : [CommentsModel] = []
    @Published var noComments = false
    @Published var newComment = false
    @Published var commentTxt = ""

    
    let ref = Firestore.firestore()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    
    var post: PostModel?
    init(post: PostModel? = nil) {
            if let post = post {
                self.post = post
            }
        getComments(id: "") //need to pass post.id to this view?
        }
    
    func getComments(id: String) {
//code for this function. All I need to really do right now is print the post.id
}
```

This should be all the code that is needed to understand this question. I'm sure this is a simple fix, but I have been trying to figure this out for four days with no luck.

**EDIT: The answer I selected works, however my comments no longer show up since getComments is not initialized. Post with this issue is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68324269/swiftui-initializing-a-function-while-using-didset)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may want to modify your `CommentsViewModel` and remove its `init` initializer and add a didSet to the `post` property:

```
class CommentsViewModel : ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var comments : [CommentsModel] = []
    @Published var noComments = false
    @Published var newComment = false
    @Published var commentTxt = ""

    
    let ref = Firestore.firestore()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    
    var post: PostModel? {
        didSet {
            if let post = post {
                getComments(id: post.id)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getComments(id: String) {
        //get comments
    }
}
```

In your `CommentsView`, add the following:

```
ScrollView {
  //existing code
}.onAppear {
  commentsData.post = post
}
```

That will trigger the `didSet` in the view model, which will call `getComments`

Comment: I'd recommend not force-unwrapping the current user like this `Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid` - instead, register an auth state handler (e.g. in an auth service), make the user an @Published property, and then use Combine to listen to any changes. See https://github.com/peterfriese/BookShelf/blob/main/code/frontend/apple/BookShelf/Shared/App/BookShelfApp.swift#L38 for an example of how to do this.

Comment: @PeterFriese good advice. I wasn't focused on that since it doesn't relate to the question, but I think it's a good point.

Comment: Removing the init simply presents my loading wheel. Initializing getComments is a requirement without totally re-doing this code. I tried adding init after the `if let post = post` however that threw an error. I believe I somehow need to initialize getComments with id: post.id in the parameters.

Comment: Is there any possible way I can still init getComments with this code? Init is required for my code to work

Comment: There's nothing inherently special about having `getComments` inside `init`. I've seen your other posts about this, and asked a couple of questions on the one you deleted. Have you used the debugger to make sure `getComments` is getting called? You refer to a loading wheel, but you never show that code in any of your questions, so it's not clear what that's referring to or what it's dependent on.

Comment: In your last question, you suspected you had to call `getComments` in two places to work (and that one had to be in `init`) -- this is definitely not the case, but we have to figure out where the current issue is. It would help if you included all of the necessary code for a [mre], or at the very least, show what the loading wheel is dependent on, and make sure you've used the debugger to see that `getComments` is getting called when you think, and also, very importantly, on the instance you think it's getting called on.